# Setting variable to result of Parse Query in promise only shows first item in response

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

My Parse Cloud Code queries all of a user's matchCenterItem instances, and uses the resulting properties of these instances as parameters in a promise function.

What I want is for every "Top 3" JSON thats returned by the promise function to have its own respective `searchTerm` value, as can be seen by the way I structured my response. I've tried doing this as you see below, but this results in every "Top 3" showing the same value for "Search Term", rather than iterating through and showing a different "Search Term" for every instance of matchCenterItem.

I think this may be because I define the `searchTerm` variable outside the promise, but I don't know how to define that within the promise, since it's an httpRequest.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("MatchCenter", function(request, response) {
    //defines which parse class to iterate through
    var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
    var query = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);
    var promises = [];

    //setting the limit of items at 10 for now
    query.limit(10);
    query.find().then(function(results) {
      for (i=0; i<results.length; i++) {

        var searchTerm = results[i].get('searchTerm');
        console.log(searchTerm);

        url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';
        //push function containing criteria for every matchCenterItem into promises array
        promises.push((function() {

          var httpRequestPromise = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({

            url: url,
            params: { 
              'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords',
              'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
              'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
              'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
              'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
              'REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder' : 'BestMatch',
              'paginationInput.entriesPerPage' : '3',
              'outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)' : results[i].get('itemCondition'),
              'itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value' : results[i].get('maxPrice'),
              'itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue' : 'USD',
              'itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value' : results[i].get('minPrice'),
              'itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue' : 'USD',
              //'itemFilter(3).name=LocatedIn&itemFilter(3).Value' : request.params.itemLocation,
              'itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value' : 'FixedPrice',
              'keywords' : results[i].get('searchTerm'),
            }
          });
          return httpRequestPromise
        })());
      }


      //when finished pushing all the httpRequest functions into promise array, do the following  
      Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(results){
        //console.log(arguments);

        var eBayResults = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          var httpResponse = arguments[i];
          var top3 = collectEbayResults(httpResponse.text)
          eBayResults.push(top3);
        };

        function collectEbayResults (eBayResponseText){
          var ebayResponse = JSON.parse(eBayResponseText)

          var matchCenterItems = [];

              //Parses through ebay's response, pushes each individual item and its properties into an array  
              ebayResponse.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.forEach(function(itemByKeywordsResponse) {
                  itemByKeywordsResponse.searchResult.forEach(function(result) {
                    result.item.forEach(function(item) {
                      matchCenterItems.push(item);
                    });
                  });
              });

              var top3Titles = [];
              var top3Prices = [];
              var top3ImgURLS = [];
              var top3ItemURLS = [];

              //where the title, price, and img url are sent over to the app
              matchCenterItems.forEach(function(item) {
                var title = item.title[0];
                var price = item.sellingStatus[0].convertedCurrentPrice[0].__value__;
                var imgURL = item.galleryURL[0];
                var itemURL = item.viewItemURL[0];

                top3Titles.push(title);
                top3Prices.push(price);
                top3ImgURLS.push(imgURL);
                top3ItemURLS.push(itemURL);
              });


              var top3 = 
              {
                "Top 3": 
                [

                    { 
                      "Title": top3Titles[0], 
                      "Price": top3Prices[0], 
                      "Image URL": top3ImgURLS[0],
                      "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[0]
                    },

                    { 
                      "Title": top3Titles[1], 
                      "Price": top3Prices[1], 
                      "Image URL": top3ImgURLS[1],
                      "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[1]
                    },

                    { 
                      "Title": top3Titles[2], 
                      "Price": top3Prices[2], 
                      "Image URL": top3ImgURLS[2],
                      "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[2]
                    },

                    {
                       "Search Term": searchTerm
                    }
                ]
              }
              return top3
        }

        response.success
        (
          eBayResults
        );

      }, function(err) {
          console.log('error!');
          response.error('DAMN IT MAN');
          });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create an array of search terms in the outer scope, like you do your promises array and populate it as you populate the promises, then pass the correct `searchTerms` item to your `collectEbayResults()` function:

```
// up top where you declare promises:
var promises = [];
var searchTerms = [];

// ... later in your loop where you populate promises:
var searchTerm = results[i].get('searchTerm');
// add it to the array just like you add the promises:
searchTerms.push(searchTerm);

// ... later in your loop to extract the promise results:
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  var httpResponse = arguments[i];
  // since they're in the same order, this is OK:
  var searchTerm = searchTerms[i];
  // pass it as a param:
  var top3 = collectEbayResults(httpResponse.text, searchTerm)
  eBayResults.push(top3);
};

// ... lastly change your method signature:
function collectEbayResults (eBayResponseText, searchTerm) {
```

The result is that when your code in that function uses `searchTerm` it will use the one passed in that matches the response.